# What could the old German (or maybe Bayrish?) word gestu:ep mean?

Tags: meaning, dialect, history

I'm digging into old German cookbooks from 1400-1600 and I came across the following book

https://www.uni-giessen.de/fbz/fb05/germanistik/absprache/sprachverwendung/gloning/tx/feyl.htm

which contains a recipe for a Sauce in which this passage is found

> vnd thue dann honig dar an vnd geribens prot vnd negellein vnd gut
> gestu:ep vnd thue sie in ein feßlein

So basically

> und tu dann Honig daran und geriebenes Brot und Nelken und [gut gestu:ep] und tu sie in ein fäßlein

The weird notation u:e simply means "an u with an e written above it" so basically ü.

Comment: This hit at Google books says "Staub" (dust), specifically "Sohlenmasse" (the dirt you get when you dig a new pit in mining, although this is archaic). Alas I do not quite see how this is applicable to cooking. https://books.google.de/books?id=hvCPo91tQAoC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=gest%C3%BCp&source=bl&ots=tIUlD1g0B5&sig=ACfU3U08Aoe7tGR9y5QE4PX8ozc-_jZvyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO98uBytPyAhVtMOwKHWyUBZUQ6AF6BAgbEAM#v=onepage&q=gest%C3%BCp&f=false

Comment: I mean "gut stauben" could mean something along the lines of "season well" given that there is some sort of ubiquitous powdery spice blend so it's not to far out there...

Comment: Perhaps this is better as a new question, but how common is writing an umlaut like that, "Gestu:ep"?

Comment: Given the cloves and the honey, and the fact that it's mentioned in Schmeller's dictionary, and that the Grimms's dictionary wasn't published before the late 1830s (and so might be up to 4 centuries older), I'd deffo go with the cinnamon powder here. Will have to try this, thanks for the question! Yum!

Fun fact: "gsälz" (for the "salsenn" used by Meister Eberhard here) is still in common usage in Swabia nowadays. My grandmother used to make stuff like what he describes all the time.

Comment: @BruceWayne Pretty uncommon, I'd say. It's used only in cases where the character is not available in the typeset and the common method of adding an 'e' is not known or deemed not to be understood by the reader (e.g. when an english printer wants to typeset a german word on an original Gutenberg printing press). In german academia in the 90ies, the method of writing "a, "o, "u became more prevalent (thanks to LaTeX: these are the escape sequences for german umlauts in 7-bit ASCII).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/gest%C3%BCpp) I tend to powdered spice ("gepülvertes gewürz") in the context with the mentioned cookbook. The spelling deviates somewhat with the search term with *gestüpp*. Nevertheless, in the given source also ***und gestüp auff jre essen gestrewet*** is found.

Original source is the [German Dictionary by Jacob Grimm and Wilhelm Grimm](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/#1).

**German:**

Nach dem [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/gest%C3%BCpp) tendiere ich im Kontext mit dem erwähnten Kochbuch zu pulvirisiertem Gewürz ("gepülvertes gewürz"). Die Schreibweise weicht beim Suchbegriff mit *gestüpp* etwas ab. Gleichwohl findet sich in der angegebenen Quelle auch *und gestüp auff jre essen gestrewet*.

Originalquelle ist das [Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob Grimm und Wilhelm Grimm](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/#1).

Comment: Yes, "gepülvertes gewürz"/"powdered spice" seems to be the best fit here. Similar entry in [Frühneuhochdeutsches Wörterbuch](https://fwb-online.de/lemma/gest%C3%BCppe.s.2n#sense4), which also lists the compound word "gestüpbeutel ›Gewürzbeutel‹".

Comment: Compare Schmeller, Bayerisches Wörterbuch: *Mode-Stupp, Nägelein-Stupp, Piment-Stupp, Pfeffer-Stupp, Rörl-Stupp*, Pimentkörner, Gewürznelken, Pfeffer, Zimt pulverisiert. [...] *stubben, stuppen,* (nürnb.) *stippen*, mit Pulver bestreuen [...] Die Speisen *stuppen* mit Pfeffer oder andern pulverisierten Gewürzen aus der *Stuppbüchsen*.